# “I know who(m) you spoke to” or “I know to whom you spoke”?

Tags: prepositions, clauses, who-whom

1. I know who(m) you spoke **to**.
2. I know who(m) it was given **to**.

According to above noun clauses, can we move the preposition 'to' before 'whom'? For example,

1. I know **to** whom you spoke.
2. I know **to** whom it was given.

Comment: @Amit I can't fathom using *two* prepositions in this construction. Otherwise, we could get "I know who you spoke to with," which I have never heard.

Comment: Usually, the "to whom" versions of your examples would be considered to be the less desirable versions, or too formal sounding -- that is, the "to whom" versions would be more appropriate for the more formal styles and formal registers. The "who" versions would be considered to be neutral style, and also used in informal style. (Also, depending on the verb in the subordinate clause, sometimes the fronting of the preposition might be awkward or might not even be allowed.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can move the preposition to before the *who(m).*

That is prefectly grammatical. In fact, many "grammarians" insist that putting *to* before the *whom* is the only correct way to write these sentences. So, more often the question is asked: Can we move the preposition to the end of the sentence? (For which answer, see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).)

So

> 1. I know who(m) you spoke to.
> 2. I know who(m) it was given to.

are perfectly natural. However, *whom* is old-fashioned and it is perfectly natural to use *who* instead, even in these sentences.

And

> 1. I know to whom you spoke.
> 2. I know to whom it was given.

are also correct. In fact, some grammarians and grammar books insist that the *to* must come before *whom* and not be moved to the end of the sentence. This rule, however, does not reflect actual English usage. Note also that the use of *whom* is also insisted upon by these same grammarians.

Comment: Is this sentence correct?                                 'We had a discussion **about** **to** whom You spoke.'

Comment: @Dinusha First, we don't capitalize pronouns in English, except perhaps when referring to God. Second, yes, that sentence would be grammatically correct, but (a) perhaps not one every "authority" on English would consider to be correct and (b) not one I would *ever* say. First, I rarely use *whom*. Second, I normally put prepositions at the end of a sentence, when it sounds natural. So: *We had a discussion about who(m) you spoke to*. Or *spoke with*.