# "Who" instead of "whom" in the objective case

Tags: pronouns, objects

Is it grammatically acceptable to use "who" instead of "whom"?

> Who does this coat belong to?

or even

> Who does he love?

I am especially interested in the second case since I know that it's gramatically incorrect but I often chanced upon such examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“I know who(m) you spoke to” or “I know to whom you spoke”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34537/i-know-whom-you-spoke-to-or-i-know-to-whom-you-spoke)

Answer (score 1):

**Whom** is proper in this case, but you will find that in the US, "whom" is rarely used, and that **who** will be accepted as normal in almost all situations by the majority of the population.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's grammatically acceptable.

> *Who does this coat belong to?* is OK

But, you need *whom* when it's preceded by a preposition

> To *whom* does this coat belong?

The latter example,

> Who does he love?

is OK, you can use *whom* instead.

---

Reference

*Oxford Guide to English Grammar, 26.3 Who and whom*

Comment: @JavaLatte I mean if the preposition *precedes* the pronoun. Grammar rules in my book are rather formal and old-fashion and it doesn't accept *to who*, maybe present-day English allows that, though.

Comment: @JavaLatte I disagree that you said *"who... to"* is incorrect. Collins Cobuild and Oxford Guide to English Grammar confirm it's grammatically correct. But Oxford Guide doesn't accept *to who*, at all.

Comment: @JavaLatte As you wish.