# Do you happen to know who I should talk to? / to whom should I talk?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm unsure whether both these sentences are grammatical, and if they are, whether one should be preferred:

A problem emerged that needs fixing.

> Do you happen to know who **I should** talk **to**?

> Do you happen to know to who**m** **I should** talk?

> Do you happen to know to who**m** **should I** talk?

to fix the problem.

Related: [“I know who(m) you spoke to” or “I know to whom you spoke”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34537/i-know-whom-you-spoke-to-or-i-know-to-whom-you-spoke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the normal, everyday sentence that almost all native English speakers would use.

The second is a stilted form which some people use in formal situations. I suspect that many people do not use it at all, and there may be a few people who use it in their normal speech.

The third is not grammatical, because embedded questions do not invert their subject and verb/auxiliary. People sometimes do use such inversion in casual speech (usually because they have changed their mind about the structure of the sentence while speaking it), but I'd be surprised if many people would do so and use "to whom" in the same sentence.

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind one more question, why shouldn't it be "...know who**m** I should talk to?" I thought that since it follows "to", it would have the added "m"

Comment: _Whom I should talk to_ is possible, but even less likely than _to whom I should talk_, for two reasons: 1) in situations where people use _whom_, they are less likely to use the (relatively informal) stranded "to"; 2) for many people it is the preceding _to_ which triggers the _whom_. That is, hardly anybody would say _to who did you talk_, but some of the people who would say _to whom did you talk_ would happily say _who did you see_ rather than _whom did you see_.